# If the probability you see car $X$ in an hour is $10\%$, what is the probability you will see that car in two hours?

Tags: probability

Probability of not seeing a car in the first hour is $0.9$. Hence, probability of not seeing a car in $2$ hours is $0.9^2.$ So the answer is $1 - 0.9^2 = 0.19$

Am I approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your working seems fine assuming independence.